# do i need to create different login page for different users

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm developing an application where in there are 3 different set of users: admin,manager,employee.
I intend to have a single log in page for all users.
based on the credentials different users will be shown different pages.
is this a good idea?

Also how do i go about designing db?
I have created `"roles" table with roles_id(primary_key) and role_name`
what next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its best to keep everything as simple and uniform as possible. Therefore I would agree that a single login page, irrespective of type of user is a good idea.

Within the table that you store the users details in an additional field that designates what type of user would be adequate. That could be the foreign key to the roles table where you provide detail of what each role can do.